# Is there a way to organize the window spread

Tags: unity

Ubuntu 20.04

I usually have some 50+ windows open, and over time, the order of the windows in the spread changes, and I end up spending a lot of time looking for the window I need.

[My Window Spread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJF9n.jpg)

Comment: It's something more gnome-like than unity. Change your tag in case. If you're using gnome it's a good idea to use worksapces. You can switch between them by Ctrl + Alt + Page Up/Down

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to organize the window spread yourself. It will adapt when windows disappear or are added to fit the windows in the display.

Opening many windows and leaving them open obviously becomes highly unmanageable at all. Ask yourself if and why you need to keep 50+ windows open in the first place.

If, after this, you still need quite a lot of Windows (definitely not 50), then it becomes usefull to organize them in different workspaces. Also the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> application switcher can come in handy if you are managing many windows. It allows to select between windows of one single application: Hold <kbd>Super</kbd>, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the desired application is highlighted, then use <kbd>` (key above tab)</kbd> to select a window of that application.

You could move from dynamic workspaces to a fixed number of workspaces, and then use the official Gnome Shell extension "Auto Move Windows" to have specific applications always open on a specific workspace. This way, you would know you need, for example, to look on Workspace 1 for Firefox windows, 2 for your file manager, etc.

Anyway, a little order and discipline on behalf of the user remains necessary when working on a computer. Get into the habit to close windows regularly and now and then close them all so you can focus easier on the ones you are working with.

Comment: Thanks vanadium! Still, it would be good if the spread organized like the Alt~ whith a most recently used policy. Most of the windows are browser windows with stuff I'm researching. The problem with workspaces in Ubuntu is that when I restart the computer, stuff needs to get reorganized. In WIndows 11, I work with workspaces because stuff gets put back into its assigned workspace, but one of my current projects require ubuntu.

Comment: BTW since I am a new software engineer (I got my MSc in computer science from UPen in 1981) I appreciate your recommendation to be more disciplined. I take it to heart and hope it will make me a better professional when I grow up. Still If the spread would organize by most recently used, it would be great!!

Comment: "Still If the spread would organize by most recently used, it would be great!! " Probably not a good idea. Windows would change position every time and thus, instead of knowing where a window is, you each time need to visually hunt it down again and again.

Comment: That's the thing, that windows keep changing position. Just open a new window and everything gets shuffled. Or When the computer starts up and loading the previous session, its a different order every time. And the new session doesn't place windows in their assigned workspace like windows does.